# Nginx odd caching or something after enabling php?

Tags: nginx

I'm not really sure what to consider this under, or the cause, so I'm sorry if the title is misleading.

I just installed Nginx for the first time and out of curiosity tried to see if I could get some popular forum software to work properly. I first tried installing Vbulletin 4, as this is what one community I host uses. PHP is being handled by php-fpm. I could get any custom page to display some simple php echo I just wrote, with any filename or directory. *http://example.com/test/test.php* or *http://example.com/test.php*, for instance.

However, when I went to try to install vbulletin through their install script, located at *http://example.com/install/install.php*, the file would just download. I double and triple checked the Nginx config for this domain, and everything seemed like it should work.

After downloading install.php a few times, I decided to attempt visiting the page in a Chrome Incognito window. Lo and behold, the install.php page no longer downloaded and the installer was prompting me for my customer id # as it should have. Then I go back to my main Chrome (not in incognito) window and try to visit the install page again, install.php gets downloaded again!

Here's the config I was using at the time:

```
server {
    listen       ip:80;
    server_name  my.domain.com;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Any insight on the cause of this issue? I can't imagine why it would serve a download of the php file for one session and then actually serve the dynamic content for another. I don't want any files accidentally getting downloaded by some random user.

Answer (score 0):

Your fastcgi_params look a little off. You have set PATH_INFO as the script name.

Try:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $document_root
```